# Hibernate alternative to creating multiple transient instances of same entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I need many queries to be unioned in order to work with my use case. I have a transient object coming in from the method. So I create new transient instances every time I want to persist an instance.

Is there any thing to avoid creating many transient instances for bulk insert use case? Am I missing something obvious?

Code layout like,

```
public boolean addDAO(Transient t)
{

Query q1 = session.createSQLQuery("select...");
while(q1.scroll.next())
{
   Transient new1 = new Transient(); // new transient instance
   session.save(new1);
}

Query q2 = session.createSQLQuery("select...");
while(q2.scroll.next())
{
   Transient new2 = new Transient(); // new transient instance
   session.save(new2);
}

}
```

Comment: Just write the insert statements?  There is no single awesome solution for using ORM to do truly bulk operations.  The first step in hibernate is to use a stateless session so that your objects go out of scope with each pass of the loop and don't have references held by the Session until it's closed.

Comment: Would be possible to change your code to work in a loop? If yes, then there might be a couple of things to do and get some performance boost. However, it still need to create a instance every time. See: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-inserts